# How to implement Summation equation in SystemVerilog constraints?

Tags: system-verilog

c=∑(a[i]*b[i]) Consider Two arrays a and b. The result,c of MAC operation of the two arrays a and b should be less than 1024. Use SystemVerilog constraints to implement above condition. Size of the two arrays can go from 1 to n and each array element stores 1 byte. We have to randomize both arrays.

Comment: Is this a homework question or an interview question?

Comment: It is an interview question.

Comment: I'll give you a hint then. Use the `sum() with()` method in a constraint.

Comment: Thanks dave for the hint. My initial guess was to used a same method. But I am not able to write a method to randomize the each element of array with given constraint. Should I declare a function to implement summation equation and call that function inside the constraint block ?

Comment: You can do your constraint using one sum() method. Any more hints will give away the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151916/discussion-between-rottenengg-and-dave-59).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I've seen your solution in chat, I'll give you what I was thinking

```
constraint c_sum { c == a.sum() with (a[item.index] * b[item.index]); c < 1024;}
```

Comment: I am getting following result using above constraint :                               
    c=     53  a=225   b=188
    c=     53  a=  4   b=217
    c=     53  a=210   b= 94
    c=     53  a=110   b=181
    c=     53  a= 99   b=  9
    c=     53  a=254   b= 36
    c=     53  a=252   b=177
    c=     53  a=222   b= 33
    c=     53  a= 37   b=103
    c=     53  a=114   b= 15
    c=     53  a=239   b=166

Comment: Code:                                                                                                                                           rand logic [7:0] a [];
        rand logic [7:0] b [];
        rand logic [20:0] c;
        
        constraint const1 {a.size <30;}
        
        constraint const2 {a.size == b.size;}
        
        constraint c_sum { 
          c == a.sum() with (a[item.index] * b[item.index]); 
                          c < 1024;}

Comment: You're getting overflow. Ttry `with (int'(a[item.index]) * int'(b[item.index]))`